# printing negative value in C++ base 8 or 16

Tags: c++

How is C++ supposed to print negative values in base 8 or 16? I know I can try what my current compiler/library does (it prints the bit pattern, without a minus in front) but I want to know what is *should* do, preferrably with a reference.

Comment: [std::setbase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setbase/)

Comment: The standard says that it's equivalent to `%x` or `%o` for `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From §22.2.2.2.2 (yes, really) of n1905, using `ios_base::hex` is equivalent to the `stdio` format specifier `%x` or `%X`.

From §7.21.6.1 of n1570, the `%x` specifier interprets its argument as an unsigned integer.

(Yes, I realize that those are wacky choices for standards documents.  I'm sure you can find the text in your favorite copy if you look hard enough.)

Comment: Essentially the same answer was given by Oli, but in a comment, so I can't upvote him!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that none of the standard output facilities support signed formatting for non-decimals. So, try the following workaround:

```
struct signprint
{
  int n;
  signprint(int m) : n(m) { }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const signprint & s)
{
  if (s.n < 0) return o << "-" << -s.n;
  return o << s.n;
}

std::cout << std::hex << signprint(-50) << std::endl;
```

You can insert an `0x` in the appropriate location if you like.

Comment: Thanks, but I was not looking for a solution! In fact I had written my own equivalent of ostream, and when I tested it afainst ostream it behaved different when printing negative numbers in non-decimal base. BTW I think your solultion gets into trouble when printing MININT, which can not be converter to positive...

Comment: Yes, interesting - that might require a separate check, and an unsigned type for the printing... about the question, I just think you cannot do it with standard C or C++ formatting tools.

Comment: Again, I did not ask how I could print negative numbers in non-10 radix, I was asking what the library was *supposed to do*!