# Converting a negative long value stored in hex in a string to a long variable in C++

Tags: c++, stream

I am trying to convert a stringstream which is in hex into a long. I came here for help, and the solution they gave (which works for short, int, and most longs) is not working for negative longs which require a minimum of 16 hex digits to represent.

Basically I have a stringstream called `hx` which I have populated with hex digits that should be equal to `-9223372036854775808`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream hx;
    hx << hex << LONG_MIN;
    cout << hx.str() << '\n';

    long value;
    hx >> value;

    cout << value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Actual Output:

```
8000000000000000
9223372036854775807
```

Expected Output:

```
8000000000000000
-9223372036854775808
```

I can't see why the hex value is converted to a positive number when the sign bit is 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, `hx << hex << LONG_MIN` will implicitly use `printf("%lx", ...)` to print the value, which [results in undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7373770/5376789) since `LONG_MIN` is not of type `unsigned long`.

Second, let's say `hx.str()` now stores the string `8000000000000000`. For the purpose of input to `value`, it is interpretted as a big **positive** number. As a result, `std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`, i.e. `9223372036854775807` [is stored in `value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and the reasoning as explained in other answer hx << hex << LONG_MIN will implicitly use printf("%lx", ...) which is of type unsigned long :

```
int main() {
    stringstream hx;
    hx <<hex << (LONG_MIN);
    cout << hx.str() << '\n';

    unsigned long value;
    hx >> value;

    cout << static_cast<long>( value ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should explicitly cast `LONG_MIN` to `unsigned long`, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: checked on two different online cpp compiler and it seems consistent :http://cpp.sh/2thu and https://repl.it/repls/LankyGoodValue

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including expected behavior, and compilers are not required to diagnose it.

Comment: Don't you think rules of signed to unsigned conversion is fixed and is not compiler dependent which means if i do unsigned int x = -1 and then cout that result will always be consistent

Comment: But there is no conversion... `LONG_INT` is passed as `long`. `printf` does not perform conversion for its argument, and it just leaves undefined if types do not match.